# How to connect the JCheckBox and JButton to show the number JAVA

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, textfield, jcheckbox

```
private JTextField textFieldSum = new JTextField(1);

public Count() {
    super("Project 2");
    super.setBounds(150, 150, 500, 500);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    super.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox("A");
    add(chckbxNewCheckBox1);
    textFieldSum.setEditable(false);
    add(textFieldSum);
    JButton btnYes = new JButton("YES");
    add(btnYes);
    BufferedReader reader;
    int counterA = 0;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
        int data;
        while ((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char charA = 'A';
            if (charA == (char) data) {
                counterA++;
            }  
        }
        textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counterA));
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println("Error Opening File: Terminating");
        System.exit(1);
    }   
}
```

Im sorry yall, but I have no idea how to use the actionListener in this case. I write a method to count a letter A in a file called in.txt and I created checkbox and a button. I want to connect the checkbox and button together. If I click the checkbox first and click button yes second, it will show me the how many letters in that file in the textfield. But I try so hard but I cant connect them lol.

Comment: I have the idea that I can make the letter unseen then when I click the checkbox first and then click the yes button second. It will make the number show out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first define a variable in your class

```
int static checkboxcheck = 0;
```

then implement onClickListener for your componenets after their declaration
for your checkbox as below :

```
chckbxNewCheckBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(schckbxNewCheckBox1.isChecked()){
                checkboxcheck = 1;
            }else{
                checkboxcheck = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

and your button like this :

```
 btnYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checkboxcheck == 1)
            {
             // do what ever you want here
            }
             else
             {
              checkboxcheck = 0;
             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should import the onclicklistener and view